# SIM800 does not take commands, I receive echos of commands

Tags: c, stm32, sim800

I am trying to get SIM800l to send text messages and make calls with STM32F103.
Problem is, I only receive echoes of my commands, if I send "AT" using uart, I get A, T as an echo. But not OK, as it should respond. My power supply is good and I am pretty sure my UART code is good too.

Does anybody had the same issue? Thank you!

```
    void uart_init2(){
     UART1_Init_Advanced(115200, _UART_8_BIT_DATA, _UART_NOPARITY, _UART_ONE_STOPBIT, &_GPIO_MODULE_USART1_PA9_10);
     USART1_CR1.B5  = 1;
     NVIC_IntEnable(IVT_INT_USART1);
}
char UART1_Read2(){
   while (!(USART1_SR & USART1_SR.B5));  // Wait until RXNE (RX not empty) bit is set
        // USART resets the RXNE flag automatically after reading DR
        return ((char)USART1_DR); // & 0xFF));
   }
void InterruptModule_1() iv IVT_INT_USART1 ics ICS_AUTO {
   receive = UART1_Read();
   buffer[buffernum++]=receive;
   }
```

And in main:

```
buffernum=0;
UART1_Write_Text("ATE0");
UART1_Write_Text("AT");
delay_ms(1000);
delay_ms(1000);
//UART1_Write_Text("AT+IPR=9600");
buffernum=0;
UART1_Write_Text("ATDXXXXXX;");
delay_ms(1000);
delay_ms(1000);
```

The result in the buffer after the code is:
[image: result of sending command ATD]

Comment: This question requires more clarity and details.

Comment: don't you need to send a newline or something after the command?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough.
I will edit the post to provide you with details.
About the newline, I am not sure, how should I do that? Currently, I have buffer where I store info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Not sure why, but everything works as expected when I add \r with the command.
Example:

```
UART1_Write_Text("AT\r");
```

Hope this helps somebody, I did not find anything similar online.

Comment: All "[Hayes commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) terminate with <cr>. It is well documented, including the wiki page.